Ошибка при создании реакт приложения
Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: todo-list@0.1.0
npm error Found: react@19.0.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   react@"^19.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm error node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm error   @testing-library/react@"^13.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\Users\MSIPC\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-12-07T05_38_38_817Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\MSIPC\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-12-07T05_38_38_817Z-debug-0.log
npm install --no-audit --save @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.14.1 @testing-library/react@^13.0.0 @testing-library/user-event@^13.2.1 @types/jest@^27.0.1 @types/node@^16.7.13 @types/react@^18.0.0 @types/react-dom@^18.0.0 typescript@^4.4.2 web-vitals@^2.1.0 failed

все зависимости я вроде тоже обновил
